# FacesMessage invoked by actionListener are not getting displayed in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have some `FacesMessage` inside my bean. I noticed that all of them which are invoked by `actionListener` are not getting displayed.

My `form` contains multiple fields having `FacesMessage` associated. At the end, it is having a submit button, which is having an `actionListener` like below-

```
<p:commandButton style="margin-top: 20px;" value="#{msg.submit}" update=":message" actionListener="#{agent.run()}" action="#{agent.showResults()}"/>
```

The `p:growl` is declared inside a `common_template.xhtml` page like this-

```
<p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
```

I am getting all the `FacesMessage` except which are invoked by above `p:commandButton`.

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 with GlassFish 3.1.2 in my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS machine.

**Objective**

Using `actionListener`, I am doing some I/O operations (time consuming operations). Based on these operations, I just want to notify to user about success/failure.

Any alternative or fix/hack?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener It give you the difference between action and actionListener.

Comment: @Tankhenk: Actually using `actionListener` I am doing some I/O operations (time consuming operations) and based on these operations, I just want to notify to user about success/failure. Any alternative or fix/hack?

Comment: Maybe you can use polling. Take a look in the primefaces showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf

Comment: @Tankhenk: How can I modify polling to notify messages i.e. `p:growl`? Can you please elaborate a lit more?